# PHP añade un espacio en un string que contiene URL con HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, string, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

**Problema**

Cuando genero una URL temporal S3 para acceder un objeto de mi bucket

```
$source = "http://mybucket...";
```

Si hago un var_dump($source) me muestra la URL correctamente

```
string(407) "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/..."
```

Entonces intento utilizar dicho string en un comando de ffmpeg (ffmpeg requiere que la URL esté entre comillas dobles)

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "' . $source . '" ...
shell_exec($cmd);
```

No funciona, y cuando hago un var_dump($cmd) la URL aparece así (un espacio en blanco entre el `https:` y el `//` )

```
 "https: //mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/..."
```

Funciona bien cuando el string contiene una URL con el protocolo de S3

```
"s3://mybucket...."
```

Quizás el problema esté en el protocolo

**Que he probado**(No ha funcionado)

- He probado `$url = str_replace(' ', '', $source);`
- He probado `$url = str_replace('%20', '', $source);`
- He probado `$url = str_replace('https: //', 'https://', $source);`
- He probado `$url = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $source);`
- He probado `addslashes($source)` en vez de poner `'"' . $source . '"'`
- He probado `escapeshellarg($source)`

**Que estoy usando**

- Php 7
- Laravel 4
- AWS-S3

Comment: Intentalo utilizando [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: has probado a escapar las barras? (

Comment: Probado, y tampoco funciona. Edito el post principal y añado el `escapeshellarg` @Marcos @Srsole

Comment: Puedes mostrar el resultado de `echo(base64_encode(substr($cmd, 0, 20)));`? Quiero ver si es un espacio u otro caracter raro.

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu problema, lo cual suele ser mala señal: https://tio.run/##PYyxDgIhEER7vmJDLqHRpbATjT9yDSJ3GOV2w3Ix@vPIWdjMZJJ5jxO3drpwYjWs5QlnMKlWlqO1@X1dwyNWlAP67D@0@JdgoGylUvFztMapGBLBRu5Aj4t2agj5tlmmKXOcYX8HbQB/l15GAyIC1eIFAknPvv@ezrrWvg

Comment: La URL no es del todo así, tiene esta forma @Trauma `"https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.mp4?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIZ6QXIJMYF4QLBSQ%2F20200924%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200924T121115Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-Signature=0c87cb8aecf431a2c50dbc172331649ce8cd3f5dd46657ac2796583c74a7f841"`

Comment: Pues sigue funcionando correctamente: https://tio.run/##TVDJTsMwEL33K6Ko0AtOY8dZSrEq04WWvQqIRUjIdSZNBFmIHQH9@WKJFnGZeZq36GnqrN5uT0Z1Vne6qmobCczOtK7Vcb9ffK9a@QbaUZ4jCrGpSvGpHFkVfQ1KO0VNR4@IFxs0rkoNpUZxJogfsPvreHF2PZ2gW/50ecMnh78q/r6umlxnBeMPMUXzKz5G8Zwbx04wbiAxMbl4Z/xiwRfPwfJxcX71NKPLy9N4eUBmxCWuOyDUwFYhEEojbLDyzDDd6GsDH63ptgucCA1s77nDBGPsP@@4OF@XkMxBJNAollV/pulXnTegWGhs/7RCtw0wV0ahXEUCZEo9LIj03WQlcUg8Dwd0ICGSiZf6SUKDwA@FJOEg8CNPhlSEaUSxPex0ZZFYzOqlaVHD2kK5Zfcsx9p936CebTmOWcMOyKzaE0eW/VLa@5vJGG63Pw

Comment: @Trauma no se que puede ser, he probado ya todo y nada. En Stackoverflow en inglés tampoco doy con la solución.

Comment: No es reproducible, solo pasa en tu máquina ... suena a *bug* de PHP, o a que estés haciendo algo con tus variables que no nos estás mostrando. Si no hay mas que lo que enseñas ... `99.99%` a que es un problema de PHP.

Comment: Sólo puedo decir que lo ejecuto en Laravel y que me pasa con https y no con s3.

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes la URL? ¿Probaste [eliminar caracteres no imprimibles](https://qastack.mx/programming/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)?

Comment: Si, ya está indicado en la pregunta las cosas que he probado y han fallado. La URL la obtengo mediante una función de S3, pero tanto el string que llega, como la varible donde lo almaceno se muestran correctamente. El error se produce al usar dicho string en el comando de ffmpeg.

Comment: Intenta con `echo json_encode($source);` y `echo json_encode($cmd);`, cuéntanos qué aparece.